# Makefile for UnitTests (universal file)

Tags: c, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, makefile, automated-tests

I've been working on a Makefile to automate Unit Tests in C. The main goal is that for any given project that follows the structure of a source and a test directory, `make` compiles the function and `make test` compiles and runs the tests.

While the `make` command works just fine, `make test` doesn't. In the configuration down under, the dependency of **test** calls the `%.exe` target, and not the `test_%.exe`.

How do I make a succesfull call for any test target, as long as it begins with "test_"?

I've tried to make a wildcard for it but it didn't work. This can be of still lack of knowledge but I hope to find some help here :)

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -Wall -Werror
CSYNTAX := -fsyntax-only -Wall

SRC = $(wildcard ./src/*.c)
DEP = $(SRC:.c=.exe)

SRCTEST = ./test/UnitTests

PATHI = ./test/UnitTests/includes

PATHU = ./test/UnitTests/Unity

INC := ./src/includes

TEST = test_$.exe


# Compilation of main program
all:    $(DEP)


syntax: *.c $(SRC) $(SRCTEST)/test_*.c
    $(CC) $(CSYNTAX) $^ $(CFLAGS) -I$(INC) -I $(PATHI)


%.exe:  *.c $(SRC)
    $(CC) $^ $(CFLAGS) -I$(INC) -o $@ 
    ./$@


# Compilation and execution of tests
test:   $(SRCTEST)/test_*.exe


test_%.exe: $(SRCTEST)/test_%.c $(SRC) $(PATHU)/unity.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -I $(INC) -I $(PATHI) -I $(PATHU) -o $@
    ./$@

clean:
    del *.exe
```

I'm using GNU gcc on MinGW 8.1.0 but also have access to a gcc Ubunutu 7.5.0 (replit.com)

Comment: It doesn't matter what GCC you're using; what version of GNU make are you using?  (run `make --version`)

Comment: on MinGW it's GNU Make 4.2.1 and on Ubuntu it's GNU Make 4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bunch of subtle issues here.

First, when your test target depends on a wildcard, its resolution is not intuitive as this is not directly expanded by `make`. If a matching file does not exist, `make` will attempt to find the rule with literal `*` in it:

```
$ cat Makefile
SRC = $(wildcard ./src/*.c)
SRCTEST = ./test/UnitTests

%.exe: $(SRC)
        echo Making $@ from $^

test: $(SRCTEST)/test_*.exe

test_%.exe: $(SRCTEST)/test_%.c $(SRC)
        echo Making $@ from $^

$ make test -dr
...
Considering target file 'test'.
 Looking for an implicit rule for 'test'.
 No implicit rule found for 'test'.
  Considering target file 'test/UnitTests/test_*.exe'.
   File 'test/UnitTests/test_*.exe' does not exist.
   Looking for an implicit rule for 'test/UnitTests/test_*.exe'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem '*'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'test/UnitTests/test/UnitTests/test_*.c'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'test_*'.
   Trying rule prerequisite 'src/foo.c'.
   Found an implicit rule for 'test/UnitTests/test_*.exe'.
    Considering target file 'src/foo.c'.
     Looking for an implicit rule for 'src/foo.c'.
     No implicit rule found for 'src/foo.c'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file 'src/foo.c'.
    No need to remake target 'src/foo.c'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file 'test/UnitTests/test_*.exe'.
  Must remake target 'test/UnitTests/test_*.exe'.
echo Making test/UnitTests/test_*.exe from src/foo.c
...
```

Assuming you don't want to create a file literally named `test_*.exe`, test binaries should have expected names, i.e.:

```
$ cat Makefile
SRC = $(wildcard ./src/*.c)
SRCTEST = ./test/UnitTests

%.exe: $(SRC)
        echo Making $@ from $^

.PHONY: test
test: $(patsubst %.c,%.exe,$(wildcard $(SRCTEST)/test_*.c))

test_%.exe: $(SRCTEST)/test_%.c $(SRC)
        echo Making $@ from $^
```

This will derive test binary names from test source files by converting their suffix from `.c` to `.exe`. (As a side note, the target itself should be phony since it does not create a real file).

With given file structure:

```
$ ls -R
.:
Makefile  src  test

./src:
foo.c

./test:
UnitTests

./test/UnitTests:
test_foo.c
```

this results in an attempt to create `test_foo.exe` instead of `test_*.exe`:

```
$ make test -dr
...
Considering target file 'test'.
 File 'test' does not exist.
  Considering target file 'test/UnitTests/test_foo.exe'.
   File 'test/UnitTests/test_foo.exe' does not exist.
   Looking for an implicit rule for 'test/UnitTests/test_foo.exe'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'foo'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'test/UnitTests/test/UnitTests/test_foo.c'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'test_foo'.
   Trying rule prerequisite 'src/foo.c'.
   Found an implicit rule for 'test/UnitTests/test_foo.exe'.
    Considering target file 'src/foo.c'.
     Looking for an implicit rule for 'src/foo.c'.
     No implicit rule found for 'src/foo.c'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file 'src/foo.c'.
    No need to remake target 'src/foo.c'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file 'test/UnitTests/test_foo.exe'.
  Must remake target 'test/UnitTests/test_foo.exe'.
echo Making test/UnitTests/test_foo.exe from src/foo.c
...
```

Still, it did not follow the test rule, but the general source rule. Why is that? Well, that's because when matching the stem (the `%` part) the directory is [prepended](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Match) to the searched targets. You can see in the output above that when `make` is `Considering target file 'test/UnitTests/test_foo.exe'`, it will look for a file `test/UnitTests/test/UnitTests/test_foo.c`, which comes from `$(SRCTEST)/test_%.c` explicitly mentioning `$(SRCTEST)` while it is also prepended automatically from the stem. Of course such file does not exist, hence the rule is rejected.

The proper fix is easy:

```
$ cat Makefile
SRC = $(wildcard ./src/*.c)
SRCTEST = ./test/UnitTests

%.exe: $(SRC)
        echo Making $@ from $^

.PHONY: test
test: $(patsubst %.c,%.exe,$(wildcard $(SRCTEST)/test_*.c))

test_%.exe: test_%.c $(SRC)
        echo Making $@ from $^

$ make -s test
Making test/UnitTests/test_foo.exe from test/UnitTests/test_foo.c src/foo.c
```

Note that it has now built the test binary from test source as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and the step by step of how to get there!